# Construct 1 dimensional array from several data files

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to code a small Python script to do some data analysis. I have several data files, each one being a single column of data, I know how to import each one in python using numpy.loadtxt giving me back a ndarray. But I can't figure out how to concatenate these ndarrays, numpy.concatenate or numpy.append always giving me back error messages even if I try to flatten them first.

Are you aware of a solution?

Ok, as you were asking for code and data details. Here is what my data file look like:

```
1.4533423
1.3709900
1.7832323
...
```

Just a column of float numbers, I have no problem import a single file using:

```
data = numpy.loadtxt("data_filename")
```

My code trying to concatenate the arrays looks like that now (after trying numpy.concatenate and numpy.append I'm now trying numpy.insert ) :

```
data = numpy.zeros(0) #creating an empty first array that will be incremented by each file after
for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
    temp = numpy.loadtxt(filename)
    numpy.insert(data, numpy.arange(len(temp), temp))
```

I'm passing the filenames when running my script with:

```
./my_script.py ALL_THE_DATAFILES
```

And the error message I get is:

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: Please add your existing code to the question!

Comment: Please post code, and a small sample of your data file format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[numpy.concatenate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy.concatenate) will definitely be a valid choice - without sample data and sample code and corresponding error messages we cannot help further.

Alternatives would be `numpy.r_`, `numpy.s_`

**EDIT**

This code snippet:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
filenames = sys.argv[1:]
arrays = [np.loadtxt(filename) for filename in filenames]
final_array = np.concatenate(arrays, axis=0)
```

Comment: Thank you it does work, but I needed to change axis=1 to axis=0.

Comment: O.k., I adjusted it in my answer.